# Apache Rewrite for images on subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a webserver and a subdomain. All of my images are stored in /public/images within my site directory for www.mysite.com. However I have a separate site directory for testing beta.mysite.com however on this page with a different git branch all of my images are broken because I did not want to copy all of the images. Is it possible to say for all image requests or for all 404 requests try looking at mysite.com?

I have found an example on another questions

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://example.com/sub_ds/test/images/$1
```

But since I am rather new to mod_rewrite im not sure what is going on or how to manipulate it to work for me.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the documentation of that module. It is very well written and comes with lots of really good examples. Should answer all your questions. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess of `beta` subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =beta.example.com
RewriteRule ^(images/.+)$ http://example.com//public/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```